# Flaky tests with redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, testing, redis

I have a unit test for caching an API key in redis (in a rails app).

redis is set to a global variable (`$redis`) with the [`connection_pool` gem](https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool). So I do `$redis.with do |redis|` to actually get the redis connection.

The issue is, my test is incredibly flaky. It has two assertions: one to test getting the expected value out and another to test that value is cached (for 10 minutes).

```rb
jwt = JWT.encode payload, private_key, "RS256"
assert_equal jwt, Foo.app_token
travel 5.minutes
assert_equal jwt, Foo.app_token
```

I can't work out why the test is so flaky. It fails maybe every 3-5 runs. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've never really used redis inside a connection pool so may well be doing something basic wrong.

The implementation of the method:

```rb
def app_token
  find_app_token || create_app_token
end

private

def find_app_token
  $redis.with { |redis| redis.get APP_KEY }
end

def create_app_token
  payload = # some payload
  JWT.encode(payload, private_key, "RS256").tap do |jwt|
     $redis.with do |redis|
       redis.set APP_KEY, jwt
       redis.expireat APP_KEY, payload[:exp]
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this happens because you are not clearing redis after every run. Unset the value in redis after assertion.

Comment: Ah, I do have a teardown hook to flushall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting it up as an answer here for more visibility.

`travel 5.minutes` stubs the `Time.now` and other related methods to increase/decrease the time by the required duration. The stubs are removed **at the end of the test**. I think by this they mean by at the end of entire execution of test suite. This might be the possible cause of the flaky test.

`travel` also gives an option to provide a block, after which the stubs are reset.
Hence, something like

```
travel 5.minutes do
 assert_equal jwt, Foo.app_token
end
```

might be a more suitable way of doing this, since it will remove the stub as soon as the required assertion is checked.
More here:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the `travel 5.minutes` statement and the test *seems* to work now, without flaking. ‍♂️

Comment: So as I understand `travel` is supposed to remove the stub on time once the assertion is completed, which I think is somehow not happening in your case. Can you try something like this
 `travel 5.minutes { assert_equal jwt, Foo.app_token }`

Comment: That has done the trick — thanks a lot @YuvrajJaiswal. (The travel is actually technically useless in this test — which is why I was happy to remove it — because, as I understand it, it won’t influence the ttl on redis. But redis is an implementation detail I don’t want in the test. So I may now keep the `travel` anyway, I don’t know. )